# How do I trigger a modal from a template that points to a controller returning an AJAX response

Tags: 8, ajax, modal-dialogs

I am trying to trigger a modal from a twig. The path of the modal is a controller that returns an AJAX response as below:

**Routing code**

```
usgbc_myaccount.get_badges_evidence_controller:
path: '/account/get-badges-evidence/{badge_type}'
defaults:
_controller: 
'\Drupal\usgbc_myaccount\Controller\GetBadgesEvidenceController::getEvidence'
_title: ''
 requirements:
_permission: 'access content'
_format: 'html'
```

---

**Controller code**

```
namespace Drupal\usgbc_myaccount\Controller;



class GetBadgesEvidenceController extends ControllerBase 
{   
/**
* @return AjaxResponse
*/
public function getEvidence($badge_type) 
{   

    $options = [
      'width' => '50%',
    ];

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand(t('Modal title'), 
 $badge_type , $options));

    return $response;
}
}
```

---

Call to router from twig template

```
<a class="use-ajax popup-dialog-class" data-type="modal" href="{{ 
path('usgbc_myaccount.get_badges_evidence_controller', {'badge_type': 
result.badge_type}) }}" data-dialog-type="modal">{{ 'Read more'|t }}</a>
```

---

When I click on the link I get the response in JSON in text area on another page. What is missing? It the approach correct? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to trigger your modal in multiple ways. Right now your twig is saying to open the href in a modal, but your controller is not return html, it's returning a json/ajax response to open its content in a modal.

To fix this you should do one of the following:

1. Update your twig to just point to the link, don't do anything there to trigger a modal. Your current ajax response from the controller is handling opening the content in a modal.
2. Update your controller to return html and leave your twig as-is. In this scenario your twig is handling making the content open in a modal.

I'm not sure about the _format parameter in your route definition, but I think you can just omit it.

Comment: Tried but opens up a text area with JSON .